# PHP/JS log of order details to text file only works in chrome, not other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, logging, safari

I have a simple PHP file which logs the details of an order to a text file.

It is used on a custom shopping cart in Drupal using the form_wizard which collects the order details (what was ordered, where to ship it, etc) to a cookie, then processes the order via PayPal.

When the user clicks the place order button, the log file saves that order info as a JSON object.

However, the PHP file seems to only log the order to the file if the user is using Chrome. If the user is using Safari, the log does not get appended.

The PHP is below:

```
<?php

logcart();

function logcart() {

    $file = 'cart.txt';

    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $customer = $_COOKIE["address"];
    $cart = $_COOKIE["votre_commande"];

    $cart_contents = $today.PHP_EOL.$customer.PHP_EOL.$cart;

    // Write the contents to the file, 
    // using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
    // and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same
    // time file_put_contents($file, $cart_contents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Along with the above PHP is the following JS:

```
function cartToLog() {

    console.log('logging the cart!');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://example.com/modules/form_example/js/logcart.php",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        contentType:    'application/json',
        data: "",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

Drupal.behaviors.select_paypal = {
    attach: function(context) {
        $('.paypal-button', context).once(function() {

            $(this).click(function(e) {

                if ($('#edit-tf-prenom').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-prenom').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-prenom').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-nom').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-nom').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-nom').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-adresse').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-adresse').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-adresse').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-code-postal').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-code-postal').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-code-postal').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-ville').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-ville').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-ville').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-pays').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-pays').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-pays').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-email').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-email').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-email').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-telephone').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-telephone').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-telephone').removeClass('error');}

                if ($('#edit-tf-prenom2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-prenom2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-prenom2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-nom2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-nom2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-nom2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-adresse2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-adresse2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-adresse2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-code-postal2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-code-postal2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-code-postal2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-ville2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-ville2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-ville2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-pays2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-pays2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-pays2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-email2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-email2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-email2').removeClass('error');}
                if ($('#edit-tf-telephone2').val() == '' ) { $('#edit-tf-telephone2').addClass('error'); } else { $('#edit-tf-telephone2').removeClass('error');}

                if (!$.cookie('livraison')) {

                    $('.livraison-error-messages').html('<p class="error medmarginsides">Sélectionnez un mode de livraison');
                    e.preventDefault();

                } else if ( ($('#edit-tf-prenom').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-nom').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-adresse').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-code-postal').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-ville').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-pays').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-email').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-telephone').val() == '') ) {

                    $('.facturation-error-messages').html('<p class="error medmarginsides">Les champs encadrés en rouge sont obligatoires');
                    e.preventDefault();

                 } else if ($.cookie('expediera')) {

                    if ( ($('#edit-tf-prenom2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-nom2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-adresse2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-code-postal2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-ville2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-pays2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-email2').val() == '') || ($('#edit-tf-telephone2').val() == '') ) {

                        $('.expediera-error-messages').html('<p class="error medmarginsides">Les champs encadrés en rouge sont obligatoires expediera');
                        e.preventDefault();

                    }

                 } else if (!$.cookie('conditions')) {

                    $('.conditions-error-messages').html('<p class="error medmarginsides">SVP, vérifiez que vous avez lu et approuver les conditions générales');
                    e.preventDefault();

                 } else {

                    deleteError('.facturation-error-messages');
                    deleteError('.expediera-error-messages');

                    // Reset cookies and return to start of order
                    $.cookie('reset', 'yes');

                    // Save address to cookie

                    address_array = [];

                    if ($.cookie('expediera')) {

                        adresse = $('#edit-tf-adresse2').val();
                        appartement = $('#edit-tf-appartement-suite2').val();
                        code_postal = $('#edit-tf-code-postal2').val();
                        ville = $('#edit-tf-ville2').val();
                        canton = $('#edit-tf-canton-province2').val();
                        pays = $('#edit-tf-pays2').val();
                        telephone = $('#edit-tf-telephone2').val();
                        instructions = $('#edit-instructions').val();

                        address_array.push({adresse: adresse, appartement: appartement, code_postal: code_postal, ville: ville, canton: canton, pays: pays, telephone: telephone, instructions: instructions});

                        address_json = JSON.stringify(address_array);

                        $.cookie('address', address_json);

                    } else {

                        adresse = $('#edit-tf-adresse').val();
                        appartement = $('#edit-tf-appartement-suite').val();
                        code_postal = $('#edit-tf-code-postal').val();
                        ville = $('#edit-tf-ville').val();
                        canton = $('#edit-tf-canton-province').val();
                        pays = $('#edit-tf-pays').val();
                        telephone = $('#edit-tf-telephone').val();
                        email = $('#edit-tf-email').val();
                        instructions = $('#edit-instructions').val();

                        address_array.push({adresse: adresse, appartement: appartement, code_postal: code_postal, ville: ville, canton: canton, pays: pays, telephone: telephone, email: email, instructions: instructions});

                        address_json = JSON.stringify(address_array);

                        $.cookie('address', address_json);

                        cartToLog();

                    }

                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

***NB:** I have changed the URL in the script snippet to [http://example.com/](http://example.com/_)*

The log file that is generated is as follows:

```
January 2, 2015, 6:11 pm
[{"adresse":"49 some street","appartement":"","code_postal":"1227","ville":"Carouge","pays":"Suisse","telephone":"079 123 45 67","email":"user@example.com","instructions":""}]
[{"order":"Pack XS","price":"99.00 CHF","cat":"Cat1"},{"order":"1 CD/DVD","price":"10.00 CHF","cat":"Cat5"},{"order":"1 Lot","price":"2.00 CHF","cat":"Cat6"},{"order":"Postpac","price":"0.00 CHF","cat":"Cat7"}]January 2, 2015, 6:11 pm
[{"adresse":"49 some street","appartement":"","code_postal":"1227","ville":"Carouge","pays":"Suisse","telephone":"079 123 45 67","email":"user@example.com","instructions":""}]
[{"order":"Pack XS","price":"99.00 CHF","cat":"Cat1"},{"order":"1 CD/DVD","price":"10.00 CHF","cat":"Cat5"},{"order":"1 Lot","price":"2.00 CHF","cat":"Cat6"},{"order":"Postpac","price":"0.00 CHF","cat":"Cat7"}]
```

I don't understand why the problem is. I see no reason why it shouldn't work on other browsers. I don't see any console errors.

Additionally, as you can see above, for some reason, when the log is appended to the file (so using Chrome) it appends the data twice. This is of minor consequence, but it would be nice to sanitise the file to only log an order detail once per order.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: The fact that it is browser dependant means that it isn't a PHP problem. PHP does not care what client the user uses.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I agree...and that is why I posted the question on the Javascript chat room. My JS knowledge is limited, so any help would be most appreciated.